# Angular 2 [(ngModal)] not working inside Bootstrap popup

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular2-template

I have one Angular 2 application and it contains a Bootstrap modal popup.

I have a textbox inside bootstrap popup. when I use,

`<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" style="width:50%; font-size:medium" [value]="txtArea" (input)="txtArea=$event.target.value"/>`

its working fine as expected. but when I try to use

`<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" style="width:50%; font-size:medium" [(ngModel)]="txtArea" />`

Comment: Provide a name attribute for the input with [(ngModel)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" style="width:50%; font-size:medium" [(ngModel)]="txtArea" name="txtArea"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining the `name` attribute solves your issue.

```
<input type="text" name="txtArea" class="form-control input-sm" style="width:50%; font-size:medium" [(ngModel)]="txtArea" />
```